# Divide all elements in the column of a sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, time-limit-exceeded, scipy

Using Python Scipy, I am trying to divide all numbers in all columns of a sparse matrix (400K × 500K, density 0.0005), by the sum of the squares of all numbers in a column.

If a column is `[ [ 0 ] , [ 2 ] , [ 4 ] ]`, the sum of the squares is 20, so after computation the column should be `[ [ 0 ] , [ 0.1 ] , [ 0.2 ] ]`.

This was my first attempt:

```
# Loading the sparse matrix
csc = np.load('sparse_matrix.npz')
csc = sp.csc_matrix((csc['data'], csc['indices'], csc['indptr']), shape = csc['shape'], dtype=np.float)

# Computing sum of squares, per column
maxv = np.zeros((csc.shape[1]))
for i in xrange(csc.shape[1]) :
    maxv[i] = sum(np.square(csc[:,i].data))

# Division of non-zero elements by the corresponding sum
for i in xrange(csc.shape[1]) :
    x,y = csc[:,i].nonzero()
    del y
    if x.shape[0] > 0 :
        csc[x,i] = np.array(csc[x,i].todense()) / maxv[i]
```

However, this seemed to take forever.  I improved the second part (using [SciPy sparse: optimize computation on non-zero elements of a sparse matrix (for tf-idf)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/scipy-sparse-optimize-computation-on-non-zero-elements-of-a-sparse-matrix-for)):

```
csc = np.load('sparse_matrix.npz')
csc = sp.csc_matrix((csc['data'], csc['indices'], csc['indptr']), shape = csc['shape'], dtype=np.float)

# THIS PART is slow
# Computing sum of squares, per column
maxv = np.zeros((csc.shape[1]))
for i in xrange(csc.shape[1]) :
    maxv[i] = sum(np.square(csc[:,i].data))

# Division of non-zero elements by the corresponding sum
csc = sp.csr_matrix(csc)
xs,ys = csc.nonzero()
csc.data /= maxv[ys]
csc = sp.csc_matrix(csc)
```

… but I wonder if the computation of squares part can be improved further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying to speed up Numpy code, it's important to scrutinize every loop. A loop that has to run in the Python interpreter can be hundreds of times slower than a vectorized loop running inside Numpy.

Also, when trying to improve the performance of code, there's no substitute for measurement. So let's set up a test case. The matrix `csc` here has the same density as yours, but is one-hundredth the size (to make the runtimes tractable):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from timeit import timeit

shape = 40000, 50000
density = 0.0005
n = np.prod(shape) * density
rowi, coli = [np.random.randint(s, size=n) for s in shape]
csc = csc_matrix((np.random.rand(n), (rowi, coli)), shape=shape)
```

Here's your sum-of-squares-by-column algorithm:

```
def sum_squares_by_column_1():
    maxv = np.zeros((csc.shape[1]))
    for i in range(csc.shape[1]) :
        maxv[i] = sum(np.square(csc[:,i].data))
    return maxv

>>> timeit(sum_squares_by_column_1, number=1)
19.718280024942942
```

So how can we get rid of that `for` loop? Well, if this were an ordinary Numpy array then we could write:

```
np.sum(np.square(csc), axis=1)
```

but this doesn't work here because [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) is a *matrix* rather than an *array* (see the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151128/68063)) and so `np.square` doesn't work. That's because `np.square(a)` just multiplies `a` by itself (as if you'd written `a * a`), and this is *matrix* multiplication when `a` is a matrix.

So what we need to do instead is to read carefully through the [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) documentation to see if there are methods for the operations we need. There's no `square` method, but there is a [`multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.multiply.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.multiply) method that does "point-wise multiplication" and a [`sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum) method that "sums the matrix over the given axis". So, putting these together:

```
def sum_squares_by_column_2():
    return csc.multiply(csc).sum(1)

>>> timeit(sum_squares_by_column_2, number=1)
0.04036429896950722
```

which is about 500 times faster.

Comment: Thanks! One query, summing over axis 1 gives me sum over rows, summing over axis 0 gives sum over columns. Isnt axis 0 supposed to be over rows, or have I misunderstood the concept.

Comment: Yes, you want `.sum(0)` rather than `.sum(1)`. Sorry about that.